# android disabling predictive text

Tags: android

I want to disalble the predictive texing.When we give an input through the softkeyboard the predictive texting should not come,i just need the code for disabling the predictive texting.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the inputType property in the XML layout or call setInputType() with one or more (seperated by |) of those values.

To disable the suggestions use text|textNoSuggestions. However the Sense UI keyboard seems to ignore that, adding textFilter works here.