# Can't disable predictive text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to disable predictive text for a given `EditText`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499709/android-disabling-predictive-text), but I still get the autocomplete by the prediction...

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S with XT9 enabled.

Anybody can help?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_field"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_searchfield"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textFilter"/>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A comment from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-to-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext) SO question suggests that the xml attribute doesn't work for some models, but that the java-method does work in these cases. So try this:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

**edit:**

As suggested in the comment below, here's an xml alternative that has worked:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

Comment: I had to set android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword". I'll accept your answer for the pointer to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with mEt_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD); and it worked for me.

Comment: This answer has its tradeoff. Try to erase a letter from the end of the text after using this method. You have to longpress the erase key and when it starts erasing, it erases all the text.

Comment: same as just textVisiblePassword

Comment: it doesn't work if you wanna show textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"

Comment: This will cause issues with multilingual keyboards.

Comment: still doesn't work for me, android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters|textVisiblePassword"

Answer (score 7):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

This solution works but you have to be careful with it. You cannot switch keyboard language on HTC devices (probably the reason is in Sense keyboard) if the flag **textVisiblePassword** is set.

So I had to set InputType from the code and to write something like this:

```
    public static int getInputTypeForNoSuggestsInput() {
    if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")) {
        return InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
    } else {
        return InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
    }
```

Comment: Works for me. Is there need of add above if condition.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me to see the right font on **hint** and on **text** using the [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/334) library is:

- Set your password `EditText` in your xml with
  `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"`
- Configure your `EditText` programmatically with:
  `passwordET.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod()`

This will:

1. Show the correct font on hint
2. Show the correct font on text
3. Show the correct font if you've got a `TextInputLayout`
4. Will not show suggestion or predictions in your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions given above didnt work for me.  So I did a workaround.

Create a InputFilter with the below in the filter method:

```
for (char ch:BLOCKED_CHARACTER_SET.toCharArray()){
                if (source != null && source.toString().contains(ch+"")) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
```

Here BLOCKED_CHARACTER_SET is a string which contains the characters which we wanna block.

Then set the edittext

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filterUsername, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(LENGTH)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for password field and still need characters masking:

```
inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod()
```